# My sorting method doesn't correctly sort the strings (Java)

Tags: java, sorting

For some reason whenever I run my code, the sorted arraylist returns gibberish. I feel like it should work since it checks to see the string with the lowest number in the "hand" arraylist and adds it to the sorted hand. This should work for every value in the unSorted arraylist and I thought it would give a fully sorted arraylist.

I was wondering if this was because I did something wrong in my sortHand method and if I could do something to fix it.

When I also tried to test it with handTest, whenever I added "R4" to the end of the arraylist "R4" would always show up at the front of the sorted arraylist. For some reason this only seems to be the case with R4 and doesn't seem to have a problem when I put any other numbers. Honestly I'm completely at a loss as to why this is.

```
public rummibot() {

    ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> hand = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> handTest = new ArrayList<String>();
    handTest.add("R5");
    handTest.add("R5");
    handTest.add("R4");
    handTest.add("R7");
    handTest.add("B4");
    handTest.add("R7");
    handTest.add("U4");
    handTest.add("R1");
    handTest.add("R6");
    handTest.add("R9");
    handTest.add("R31");
    handTest.add("R42");
    handTest.add("R4");
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        int temp = i + 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            deck.add("R" + temp);
            deck.add("B" + temp);
            deck.add("U" + temp);
            deck.add("O" + temp);
        }
    }
    deck.add("M1");
    deck.add("M2");

    for (int k = 0; k < 14; k++) {
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * deck.size() - 1) + 0;
        hand.add(deck.get(rand));
        deck.remove(rand);

    }
    System.out.println(deck.size());

    ArrayList<String>holder1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int l = 0; l <hand.size(); l++) {
        System.out.print(hand.get(l));
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    holder1 = sortHand(handTest);
    hand = holder1;


    for (int l = 0; l <holder1.size(); l++) {

        System.out.println(holder1.get(l) + " ");

    }


}

public ArrayList<String> sortHand(ArrayList<String> unSorted) {

    ArrayList<String> Sorted = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(unSorted.size()>0) {
        int lowest = Integer.parseInt(unSorted.get(0).substring(1));

        //System.out.println(lowest);
        int check = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < unSorted.size(); i++) {
            int tempCheck = Integer.parseInt(unSorted.get(i).substring(1));

            if (tempCheck < lowest) {
                tempCheck = lowest;
                check = i;

            }

        }

        Sorted.add(unSorted.get(check));

        unSorted.remove(check);



    }


    return Sorted;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new rummibot();
}
```

}

Comment: If you're sorting Strings, R4 will always appear before R42.  Change the R4 to R04.  Better yet, create a Card class with separate suit and value fields, and sort by Card.  Finally, class names start with a capital letter.  Rummibot, rather than rummibot.

Comment: Are you allowed to use java.util.Comparator class for this ?

Comment: Yeah this is just me trying things out on my own so I can use whatever class.

Comment: You have a bug in method `sortHand()`. This line: `tempCheck = lowest;` should be swapped, i.e. it should be: `lowest = tempCheck`. Also, I suggest you [edit] your question and post the "sorted" hand that you expect to get.